# JIRA LDAP query - add multiple OUs

Tags: active-directory, jira, ldap-query

Domain structure:

```
 company.local
  |
  Company               OU=company,DC=company,dc=local                             
  |   |-Groups          OU=groups,OU=company,DC=company,dc=local
  |     |-Admins        OU=admins,OU=groups,OU=company,DC=company,dc=local
  |        |- Service   OU=Service,OU=admins,OU=groups,OU=company,DC=company,dc=local            
  |       
  |    
  disabled              OU=disabled,dc=company,dc=local
  |
  |
  |
  jira                 OU=jira,dc=company,dc=local
     |-Jira OU1
     |-Jira OU2
     |-......
     |-Groups
          |-programs OU=programs,OU=Groups,ou=jira,dc=company,dc=local
```

JIRA LDAP authentication:

[image]

User Schema settings

[image]

User Object filter: `(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(!(cn=*{*}*)))`

With above config i can synchronize `OU=jira,dc=company,dc=local`

I want to include users in following OUs in filter:

```
OU=admins,OU=groups,OU=company,DC=company,dc=local
OU=disabled,dc=company,dc=local
```

I edited user object filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)(|(memberOf=dn=OU=jira,dc=company,dc=local)(memberOf=dn=OU=admins,OU=groups,OU=company,DC=company,dc=local)))
```

add removed additional user DN

And now i'm getting no any AD user

Can i somehow include these 2 OUs without creating separate user directories ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: done, sorry, but after answering to my own questions, i can't mark them immediately but need to wait for 2 hours, meanwhile i forget it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of googling found out that filter by ou doesn't work,ended up using multiple directories.